# gcm push notifications, progressive webapp

Tags: android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging, progressive-web-apps

I followed the google documents to create a progressive webapp and I've just implemented push notifications, however whenever I close the app I don't get any notifications.

Other apps like whatsapp seem to be able to send those notifications is there a difference between native notifications and gcm push notifications from a progressive webapp?

Comment: By *close app*, do you mean that your app is in background or force stopped?

Comment: well I swipe it away, the same way I swipe whatsapp away - but whatsapp still sends notifications, my webapp doesn't.

Comment: Which browser are you using for trying your progressive web app?

Comment: well chrome on android

Comment: For push notifications you can use everything from Chrome in Android and new Android Browser and even the new Samsung Browser

Comment: Can you point to the document you followed, please?

Comment: @Salva its an accumulation of dozen of youtube video i saw from io to progressive web application summit. and you can always check this site for insights : https://jakearchibald.github.io/isserviceworkerready/

Answer (score 3):

There absolutely no difference between the two, the rendering part is the same, it just that native ones are the notifications that comes from a **apk** generated app and the other one is rendered using **google chrome** or any web browser that support the functionality.

Beside the **service worker** with the help of **manifest.json** file will use the **GCM ( Google Cloud Messaging)** to send notifications to end users.

I worked and implemented such functionalities before, and I got my notification directly to the browser and my android phone as well, therefore I created a Github repo with nice documentation that simulate just that using Nodejs and simple web interface, please feel free to check I guess it holds what you seek :

Link : https://github.com/houssem-yahiaoui/webpush-notification